# Java.lang.verifyerror how do I fix or even find out the root cause?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, verifyerror

[image]Currently going through a nightmare attempting to fix a java.lang.verifyerror, was having issues with eclipse so I decided to uninstall and reinstall it, everything seemed normal until I tried to launch the app, thats when I noticed that I couldnt launch the app anymore, everytime I try to lauch it it crashes and gives me this error, however I have no clue what is causing it as the error log gives me little clues and I cant find any concrete answers on the internet, can anyone tell me what is wrong based on my logcat? any help will go a long way thanks

```
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624): java.lang.VerifyError: com/vineline/second/OTweetApplication
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3909)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1184)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-26 23:11:45.391: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The `dalvik.system.NativeStart.main` method throws the error. Is this some class of yours or .. ?

Comment: I didnt make this class seems like a system thing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a problem with ADT v22.  It is pretty hard to fix.  There are some suggestions here: [The CommonsBlog - Don't Manually Modify Your Eclipse Build Path... Except Now for R22](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/23/do-not-manually-modify-eclipse-build-path-except-now-r22.html) (thanks to StreetsOfBoston and CommonswareGuy)

Comment: simply, include the project in "order and export" that solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, as far as I'm aware, Android uses a different class file format and if you are running a third party JAR/Java files, you have to first run them through the `dx` tool that ships with the Android SDK.

Other possible reason may probably be some method in a `java.lang` class that is not supported on the Android SDK level you are using (for instance, `String.isEmpty()`).

Comment: how does the dx tool work? I have never had to use this up until today is this a new requirement?

Comment: Also how would I know if that is the problem, eclipse isnt giving me any clues as to anything

Comment: You can find info about the `dx` tool here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/

Comment: Also, Look in the `Library` section of the Android project preferences, below the list of SDK versions. Do your external projects you're relying on in your build show up there, with a green tick next to them?

Comment: they are there but no green tick, does this mean they arent in teh build path?

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot of my library

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by @G. Blake Meike doesn't work for you for whatever reason, here's another way of fixing it.

> 1. Right Click Project > Build Path > Configure Build Path
> 2. Click on Android on left
> 3. On right select any other Target Name/API other than 4.2.2 since it seems that's with problems.
> 4. Hit OK (At this point it rebuilds your projects with the selected API)
> 5. Run the Application

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just enabled the 3rd party library in the "Import and export" TAB of configuring build path.

[image]