# Android AsyncTask java.lang.VerifyError Error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Here's the function being called

```
public void getData() 
{ 
    ParseDataFromInternet asyncObjectName = new ParseDataFromInternet(); 
    asyncObjectName.execute(); 
}
```

This is my AsyncClass

```
private class ParseDataFromInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{ 
    //Background thread 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... a)  
    { 
        //do something
        return null; 
    }   

}
```

//Getting this error on: ParseDataFromInternet asyncObjectName = new ParseDataFromInternet();

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com.raymongulati.bbmalertandroidandios.MainActivity$ParseDataFromInternet
at com.raymongulati.bbmalertandroidandios.MainActivity.getData(MainActivity.java:90)

//The getData() function
at com.raymongulati.bbmalertandroidandios.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:79)
```

Basically, whenever I make a new AsyncTaskObject, i'm getting VerifiyError. Any idea's why?
This is for android application development. I don't have this error on my phone, but some people have reported it.

Comment: what is MainActivity.java line number 90

Comment: where do you call `getData()`.

Comment: What android versions are those people running in comparison to you or other people without errors??

Comment: Line 90 is: ParseDataFromInternet asyncObjectName = new ParseDataFromInternet();

Comment: getData() is being called whenever I want the AsyncTaskClass to run and get the data from server.

Comment: @user3165098 asked : "I have Android Studio 0.4.4 with the same error, exist any solution ?"

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with ADT 22.0.

If you're unable to just update ADT, [you can find a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764584/java-lang-verifyerror-how-do-i-fix-or-even-find-out-the-root-cause).

Comment: I have ADT 22.2.1 installed, but i'm still having this error.