# java.lang.VerifyError when running Android tests with testCoverageEnabled = true

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I've recently tried the new Jacoco code coverage feature for Android Gradle plugin, and unfortunately it makes my tests fail with the following error:

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: com/foo/bar/rest/SomeClass at
 com.foo.bar.test.rest.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:87) at
 android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190) at
 android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175) at
 android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
 at
 android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

I enabled the code coverage using these lines in build.gradle:

```
 buildTypes {

         debug {
             testCoverageEnabled = true
         } 
...
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Are you using Dagger? It seems there's an incompatibility between the offline instrumentation done by Jacoco and Dagger.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Dagger. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Here is the bug report : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174

Comment: I get this and I'm not running Dagger

Comment: Are you running Proguard in these debug builds?

Comment: @Egor Have you solved this?

Answer (score 4):

Turning @ben75's comment into an answer: The [corresponding bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174) has been fixed with [build-tools 21.0.0](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html). However, that version introduced another [Windows-specific bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629), so you should use build-tools 21.0.2 instead (even though that version does not yet show up on the [revisions page](https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html)).

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer: upgrade `android{buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"}}`

Comment: Yes: Upgrading my build tool to `21.1.2` from `19.1.0` fixed my Tests failures with `java.lang.VerifyError`.  Thanks @Some-Noob-Student

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same problem, but found this solution:
add -noverify to your gradle file like so:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        all {
            // configure the test JVM arguments
            jvmArgs '-noverify'
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/144

Answer (score -2):

You'll receive a  `java.lang.VerifyError` anytime there is inconsistency  between the library used during compilation and run-time.

Here's another thread that lists similar issue : [Java.lang.verifyerror how do I fix or even find out the root cause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764584/java-lang-verifyerror-how-do-i-fix-or-even-find-out-the-root-cause)