# Async task freezes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

At no time que instantiate my object `EmailTask` the error occurs.

```
public void send(View view){
       EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Switch iluminacao = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        Switch wifi = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        RatingBar mBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        try {
            EmailTask asyncTask = new EmailTask(text.getText().toString(), iluminacao.isChecked(), wifi.isChecked(), mBar.getNumStars());

            asyncTask.execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }          
    }
```

My AsyncTask

```
package com.morais.daniela.conectasp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;

import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

/**
 * Created by daniela.morais on 24/03/15.
 */
public class EmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String comments;
    private boolean getIluminacao;
    private boolean getWifi;
    private float getStars;
    private SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();

    /**
     * Recebe feedbacks enviados pelo usuario e inicializa configuracoes do email
     * @param comments
     * @param getIluminacao
     * @param getWifi
     * @param getStars
     */
    public EmailTask(String comments, boolean getIluminacao, boolean getWifi, float getStars) {
        this.comments = comments;
        this.getIluminacao = getIluminacao;
        this.getWifi = getWifi;
        this.getStars = getStars;
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("conectasaopaulo@gmail.com.br","senha"));
    }

    /**
     * Encaminhar email
     * @param params
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String iluminacao = "Não.";
        String wifi = "Não.";
        if(getIluminacao==true){
            iluminacao = "Sim.";
        }
        if(getWifi==true){
            wifi = "Sim.";
        }

        try {
            email.setFrom("conectasaopaulo@gmail.com.br");
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setSubject("Feedback - ConectaSP");
            email.setMsg("Houve problemas com a iluminação? " + iluminacao + "\n\n"
                    + "Houve problemas com o wifi? " + wifi + "\n\n"
                    + "Avaliação geral " + getStars + "\n\n"
                    + "Comentários:\n" + comments + "\n\n"
                    + "Informações gerais do aparelho\n" + Build.DEVICE + "\t" + Build.HARDWARE + "\t" + Build.MODEL);
            email.addTo("dani.m@hotmail.co.uk");
            email.send();
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro ao enviar email.");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Error

```
03-24 16:10:13.790    7215-7215/com.morais.daniela.conectasp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3103)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/morais/daniela/conectasp/EmailTask
            at com.morais.daniela.conectasp.FeedbackActivity.send(FeedbackActivity.java:50)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project, it can be caused by library changes

Comment: Looks like you are using some external jars. Can you check your build path? This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764584/java-lang-verifyerror-how-do-i-fix-or-even-find-out-the-root-cause

Comment: The problem is in `FeedbackActivity.java:50`, which is your `send()` function. Can you share?

Comment: This will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10677757/3681056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like maybe you either require a permission you don't have, or you require a newer version of the OS to run on.

Please check FeedbackActivity and make sure you aren't using any SDK calls that won't run on the device with which you are testing.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I don't know all the code that's being run and I'm looking at the VerifyError that's spit out and it indicates there something wrong with the code, such as using an SDK method that's not supported on a particular OS. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror.

Comment: Man you guys are tough. Does my comment above help?

Comment: For incredible as it may seem (because of the negative votes in his response) is correct, the problem was Gmail email access permission on application "unknown".