# Java.lang.verifyError android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, verifyerror

I am just opening camera clicking a photograph, not using any library.
The code was working fine suddenly this error showed up.
Created new project, restarted Android studio, rebooted test device but same issue.

Stack trace :

```
    05-07 20:20:46.426 8271-8271/com.cameraprototype.findcamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cameraprototype.findcamera, PID: 8271
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/cameraprototype/findcamera/MainActivity
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2276)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the java code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java.lang.verifyerror how do I fix or even find out the root cause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764584/java-lang-verifyerror-how-do-i-fix-or-even-find-out-the-root-cause)